# Emacs ESS key bindings

Tags: emacs, latex, elisp, ess

I am trying to set some key bindings for ESS. I read one way is:

```
(eval-after-load "ess-mode"
  '(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "<f5>") 'myfunc))
```

But this works only inside the code blocks delimited by `<<>>`, `@`.

Another problem is that I would like to use the same key both for plain LaTeX mode (a .tex file) and LaTeX as part of Noweb (a .rnw file) and so I can't just define the key twice for LaTeX mode and ESS mode.

While there is a `LaTeX-mode-hook`, I don't see something like `` `ess-noweb-mode-hook ``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error, I found the answer.

If we are in a LaTeX only buffer this is true: `(and (equal (symbol-name major-mode) "latex-mode") (not ess-noweb-mode)))`.

If we are outside chunks of an ESS buffer this is true: `ess-noweb-mode`.

You may be interested to the following convenience functions.

```
;Check ESS related modes 
(defun is-pure-latex ()
  "The buffer is in LaTeX mode, but not in ESS mode."
  (and (equal (symbol-name major-mode) "latex-mode") (not ess-noweb-mode)))

(defun is-ess ()
  "The buffer is in ESS mode."
  ess-noweb-mode)

(defun is-ess-doc ()
  "The buffer is in ESS mode and insertion point is outside a chunk."
  (and ess-noweb-mode (equal (symbol-name major-mode) "latex-mode")))

(defun is-ess-chunk ()
  "The buffer is in ESS mode an insertion point is inside  a chunk."
  (equal (symbol-name major-mode) "ess-mode"))

(defun is-ess-inf ()
  "The buffer is in inferior ESS mode"
  (equal (symbol-name major-mode) "inferior-ess-mode"))
```

Answer (score 2):

ess-noweb mode is just a wrapper and it loads latex-mode and R-mode in corresponding chunks. So if you define a shortcut in `latex-mode-map` it should be available in .rnw buffers as well.

Comment: There should be a way to distinguish between the non-chunk mode of a .rnw buffer and a .tex buffer.